# Webserver and FreeNAS storage server

Tags: storage, truenas

I have a web server running currently which is low on free storage space and many more files are incoming. 
I want to store files from that web server onto another server (NAS, FreeNAS server).
An example: someone wants to download a PDF file from the website (on the web server), but the file will be downloaded from the FreeNAS server.
Is this possible? Can I use FreeNAS for this?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just export storage from the FreeNAS server via NFS, which is then mounted on the web server. The web application then does not even need to be aware in any way that its storage is remote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Deploy FreNAS/NAS. Mount NAS to your web server. Use the mapped storage/volume/directory as storage for your websites. However, this kind of setup is okay for home media/web servers/lab, but for production usage, I would recommend you take more hardware and setup one more web server.